# Mapping data in Textarea defualtValue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm just trying to map the data into `defaultValue` of `textarea` everything works fine but when I'm trying to make a line break using `\r` it works as supposed but

**Why i'm getting an comma before each line?**

```
<textarea defaultValue={ this.state.data.map(data => data.name+'\r') } />
```

[image]

Comment: Because you are transferring an array into a string context ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implicitly converting an array to a string.

That calls the `toString` method of the array which (internally) calls `this.join(",")`.

```js
var my_array = [];
my_array.push("This");
my_array.push("is");
my_array.push("an");
my_array.push("array");
document.write(my_array);
```

If you don't want commas, then call `join()` yourself to explicitly convert it to a string.

NB: new lines in JS are typically expressed as actual new lines (`\n`) and not carriage returns (`\r`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I used join instead of map the data aren't displaying :( https://prnt.sc/ji6aju

Comment: @Lauradelgado — I missed that you were extracting the name property. You still need map. You just need to call `join` explicitly.